# Composing a Tire query from multiple ruby blocks

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, metaprogramming, tire

Tire allows you to build up an elasticsearch query using a DSL designed to mirror the JSON api, for example:

```
search = Tire::Search::Search.new

search.query do
  boolean do
    should { match :title, "Red" }
    should { match :synopsis, "Red" }
    should { match :brand_title, "Red" }
  end

  boolean do
    must { term :excluded, false }
  end
end
```

I'd like to separate this out into my own DSL to define groups of queries that can be built up, kind of like Rails scopes:

```
class Proxy
  def initialize
    @queries = []
  end

  def results
    search = Tire::Search::Search.new
    queries = @queries

    search.query do
      # …? What should go here to search the combined set of conditions?
    end
  end

  def term t
    query do
      boolean do
        should { match :title, t }
        should { match :synopsis, t }
        should { match :brand_title, t }
      end
    end
  end

  def included bool
    query do
      boolean do
        must { term :excluded, !bool }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def query &block
    @queries << block
  end
end

p = Proxy.new

p.term "Red"
p.included true

p.results
```

The problem is, Tire doesn't allow for more than one `search.query` block - subsequent `query`s replace the previous one. Can I use something like instance_eval to run multiple blocks in the correct context of the query block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the blocks can just be run using instance_eval and they execute in the correct context:

```
def results
  search = Tire::Search::Search.new
  queries = @queries # Only local variables are available inside the query block below

  search.query do
    queries.each do |q|
      instance_eval(&q)
    end
  end
end
```

I was almost certain I'd tried this before I asked this question, but I guess I messed up before.

Comment: Any idea if this would work with filters like :term as well? I tried, bit it seems as only the last proc to be instance_eval'd get's sent ES. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with tire, but have experience in elasticsearch Query DSL. I think the issue is that the search API only allows one `"query": {...}` in the JSON that is sent to the `_search` endpoint.

Think about it this way, if you had more than one query, how would elasticsearch know how to combine them. You need to use another `bool` query to do so.

The `"query"` is the root of a (possibly large) query tree, you can't have more than one root!

Hope I could help...

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm happy with that constraint. Maybe the title was misleading, but I'd be really happy to find a way in Ruby, that I can build up that one single query but from separate Ruby method calls.

Comment: I can't help with ruby I'm afraid, but I did do something similar in php with elastica (equivalent of tire). I had methods which added to a root `bool` query (to either the `must` or `should` clause) by appending the query onto the end of array. Something like `function addShould($newQuery) { $this->should[] = $newQuery; }`

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the documentation. Check here http://karmi.github.io/tire/#section-84.

You can call them like

```
Tire.search('articles') { query { boolean &tags_query } }
```

and just build your own lambdas.